# we have Jenkins on windows server and when we run MSBuild/exe /t:Rebuild command to scan .net framework project then getting below error

Tags: sonarqube

Error :
error MSB4062: The "IsTestByReference"
task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\dynamics-test-projects-master\dynamics-test-projects-master\30_11_2022_From_Amit.sonarqube\bin\SonarScanner.MSBuild.Tasks.dll. Could not lo
ad file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  d
eclaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\dynamics-test
-projects-master\dynamics-test-projects-master\30_11_2022_From_Amit\tests.CRMContractedInvoices\tests.CRMContractedInvoices.csproj]

Command :
1)SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"projectname" /d:sonar.host.url="http://sonarqube.com" /d:sonar.login="login token"

2. MsBuild.exe /t:Rebuild